ubuntu system menu not showing some options
I want to connect to va wireless network, so I used my other computer to search up how to do so (searching on ubuntu displayed an error). Ubuntu said to click the system menu to see wifi, so I did, but the system menu was not showing some things. For example, an Ubuntu system menu should look like this, but it instead looked like this.

In general, it is always a good idea to state the version of your distribution, e.g. Ubuntu 23.04 or 23.10 If you are not sure which version you are using, type this into your terminal: lsb_release -a
Or go to the settings menu (it is shown in your second attached picture). There, scroll down to "About". Here the OS Version is stated also.
Concerning your question, stay in the settings menu and first click on the very top on "Wi-Fi" and see if it is turned on (the radio button on the top right corner of the Wi-Fi submenu) needs to be on the right side. Let us know if the issue persists.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I am on version 22.04.

https://i.sstatic.net/x1Isu.pngthis is just an extension added to ubuntu, you have to click the settings in the second picture to get to wifi settings.

Did you manage to resolve this topic @SoloX ?
